# How to encode/decode a long long property with NSCoder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nscoder

How to decode a **long long** type property in `initWithCoder:` and encode in `encodeWithCoder:` with NSCoder in iOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On iOS a `long long` is 64 bit, so use the `encodeInt64: forKey:` and `decodeInt64ForKey:` methods.