# Archiving an object in Dot Net and unarchiving in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, serialization, deserialization, archive

I have a web service which is written in DotNet and returns a archived class object which I need to unarchive in a Cocoa app.

Is this possible?

I tried to use the information in [How to encode/decode a long long property with NSCoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486612/how-to-encode-decode-a-long-long-property-with-nscoder), but I don't know the key to decode it, and my attempts caused a crash.

Should I be using `NSCoder`, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I would serialize and deserialze in a well known interchange format, like YAML, XML(XML::RPC, SOAP) or JSON, I would probably go with JSON. if you are on iOS and able to target only iOS 5.0 and later; then there is a built in class [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), otherwise you should investigate [SBJSON](http://superloopy.io/json-framework/).

Comment: Yes Grady For these formats it is possible but I am talking about archiving and unarchiving the class object from DotNet to iOS. And Yes I am targeting iOS 6.0 or above.

Comment: Class Object? including methods, ie, you want to be able to save and subsequently run .net code natively on a Mac Or iOS device?

Comment: No I just want to extract data out of it use this data in my objective C class.

Comment: if you really mean class, rather than instance of class, then you should serialize that data too, one object for class data, which you will store in objective c land once, and each instance would be a seperate object also.